# How to convert vtk to stl in python?

Tags: python, converters, vtk

I have around 500 vtk files that need to be converted to stl file. I usually use Paraview to convert them manually, but it takes forever. I wonder if there is a tool to convert vtk files into stl files in Python? I attached a screenshot of my VTK file.

Thanks in advance.

[My VTK file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHbJJ.png)

Comment: Do you really need to use Python or does any batch-processing tool would satisfy you ?

Comment: I only know how to use Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like the following? Save the code as `file_converter.py` and run the script with arguments:

```
python file_converter.py -h
python file_converter.py <path-to-input-dir> -o <path-to-output-dir>
```

And here the code for the converter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import vtk
import argparse

def convertFile(filepath, outdir):
    if not os.path.isdir(outdir):
        os.makedirs(outdir)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        basename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        print("Copying file:", basename)
        basename = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]
        outfile = os.path.join(outdir, basename+".stl")
        reader = vtk.vtkGenericDataObjectReader()
        reader.SetFileName(filepath)
        reader.Update()
        writer = vtk.vtkSTLWriter()
        writer.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
        writer.SetFileName(outfile)
        return writer.Write()==1
    return False

def convertFiles(indir, outdir):
    files = os.listdir(indir)
    files = [ os.path.join(indir,f) for f in files if f.endswith('.vtk') ]
    ret = 0
    print("In:", indir)
    print("Out:", outdir)
    for f in files:
        ret += convertFile(f, outdir)
    print("Successfully converted %d out of %d files." % (ret, len(files)))

def run(args):
    convertFiles(args.indir, args.outdir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="VTK to STL converter")
    parser.add_argument('indir', help="Path to input directory.")
    parser.add_argument('--outdir', '-o', default='output', help="Path to output directory.")
    parser.set_defaults(func=run)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ret = args.func(args)
```

Comment: Hello I am trying to use this script but getting the error: 

2022-04-23 20:01:34.472 (   0.593s) [        951D71C0]vtkDemandDrivenPipeline:756    ERR| vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0x560b7516e330): Input for connection index 0 on input port index 0 for algorithm vtkSTLWriter(0x560b74991320) is of type vtkUnstructuredGrid, but a vtkPolyData is required.

Comment: @S.Funmajer Not everything that can be represented as an unstructured grid can be stored as STL. STL is exclusively for surface meshes. If your geometry indeed represents such a surface mesh, you have to modify the above script and insert a [GeometryFilter](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkGeometryFilter.html) between reader and writer. [Here's](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/PolyData/GeometryFilter/) an example.